# Comparing Data Values in Two Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am having trouble with a Java assignment. I need to construct a program that will allow someone to enter 6 numbers from a lottery. The user will then enter another 6 numbers from their ticket. The program will then check how many matches there are for that draw. Any ticket that has less than 3 matches is not a winner. I need to provide a message that states whether there are 3, 4, 5 or 6 matches. I cannot find anything in my course notes for this. Below is the code I have written so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
//Activates scanner utility

public class lottery 
{
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Names scanner, completes activating scanner

        int array1[] = new int [6];
        System.out.print("Enter Winning Numbers:");
        for(int j=0;j<array1.length;j=j+1){
            array1[j] = in.nextInt();   
        }

        System.out.print("Winning Numbers Are: ");
        for(int j=0;j<array1.length;j=j+1){
            System.out.print(array1[j]+" ");
        }

        int yourNumbers[] = new int [6];
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Enter Your Numbers:");
        for(int j=0;j<yourNumbers.length;j=j+1){
            yourNumbers[j] = in.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Your Numbers Are: ");
        for(int j=0;j<yourNumbers.length;j=j+1){
            System.out.print(yourNumbers[j]+" ");
        }

        System.out.println();
        if(array1==yourNumbers){
            System.out.println("6 Numbers Match - JACKPOT WINNER!!!");;
        } else {
            System.out.print("Not a Winner - Better Luck Next Time.");
        }

        in.close();
        //Deactivates the scanner utility
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

f1zz0_13's answer works if positioning doesn't matter. 
If the numbers need to be the same and in the same position then do something like this:

```
//your code:
System.out.println("Your Numbers Are: ");
for(int j=0;j<yourNumbers.length;j=j+1){
   System.out.print(yourNumbers[j]+" ");
}

//new stuff:
System.out.println();
int similar = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if(array1[i] == yourNumbers[i]) {
        similar++;
    }
}

if (similar >= 3) {
    System.out.println(similar + " Numbers Match - JACKPOT WINNER!!!");
}
else {
    System.out.print("Not a Winner - Better Luck Next Time.");
}
//close the scanner then end the function...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
      if (array1[i] == yourNumbers[j]) {
          count++;
          break;
      }
```

Assuming the 6 lottery numbers are unique, adding this bit of code after you have taken the input should give you how many numbers match with the lottery numbers in the variable `count`.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Where in the program should I place this?